# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Please assist

Tags: python

I'm new to python and can't figure this out. I tried following other peoples instructions on stack but nothing has resolved this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Elliot\Documents\python_work\Projects\Snake.py", line 20, in <module>
    w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Tried to find resources on stack.

Comment: Always believe the error messages, they tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` operator yields a float, even when applied between integers. For integer division, use `//`.

Comment: Note: this is true for python3, python2 would return an integer (e.g. 2 / 3 returns 0 in python2 and 0.6666666666666666 in python3)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#displaying-text), the `addch()` function only accepts strings or integers. I think your input arguments here:

```
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
```

are becoming floats since you are dividing the screen height and width by 2 here:

```
food = [sh/2, sw/2]
```

I would suggest to replace the input arguments by the following:

```
w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)
```